# rake assets:precompile with sprockets on Heroku memory exceeded

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake, assets

What seems to be running perfectly for me locally, and under 100MB of memory, seems an impossible task on the Dyno of a Heroku server...

How can I find out what is causing this memory swalling in the task itself?

```
$heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile -a myapp            

Running `rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal... 2014-09-21T22:35:19.129047+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` by example@domain.com
up, run.3387
2014-09-21T22:35:38.348540+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Awaiting client
2014-09-21T22:35:38.410272+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
2014-09-21T22:35:38.489421+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: State changed from starting to up
RSpec is not part of this bundle, skip specs.
Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /app/.sass-cache/cce550dafbc86189868cd4c9d7eaf6d5c3eab036/application.sassc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007f009904f9e8>
2014-09-21T22:36:04.665412+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Process running mem=687M(134.3%)
2014-09-21T22:36:04.665737+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-09-21T22:36:24.743579+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Process running mem=689M(134.7%)
2014-09-21T22:36:24.743579+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-09-21T22:36:44.586205+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Process running mem=691M(135.0%)
2014-09-21T22:36:44.586205+00:00 heroku[run.3387]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

"ls -la" seems to list the correct assets, that were compiled on deploy successfully. However when the app starts up, Sprockets fails to find the files contained in public/assets/*, Could it be a permissions error?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

From Heroku Support:

Hi there,
It looks like asset compilation isn't completing successfully when building the slug:

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   RSpec is not part of this bundle, skip specs.
   Warning. Error encountered while saving cache /tmp/build_c2c58e6a-e133-4fa2-8ad1-29d0e1a3f106/.sass-cache/b8f882ea75af7a30f0356eee89e2cb5703efe81b/application.sassc: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x007fd865e70118>
   Asset precompilation completed (20.48s)
```

You probably know a lot more about your app's asset pipeline than I do though. The build seems pretty big, it's pulling in a JVM which I'm guessing is for 'yui-compressor'? You might like to consider moving away from gems using Java. We have to drag in a JVM and it takes a lot of disk space. It could be what's going on here. Without the JVM you would have much more disk available for the asset compile.

---

Using :scss as css_compressor option in Sprockets solves the issue, and the result is pretty much the same.